# Sonarqube plugin development 'Decorator' alternative?

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube5.2

With the release of sonarqube 5.2, the decorator and batch components have been deprecated. Going through the code I found that they want us to use MeasureComputer instead.

Now, I had a plugin which needs the email settings of the sonar setup, fetch some basic user information and the assignee of each issue.

How do I access the email settings and user information?

**Update**
As per this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2119), the data associated to the analysis is sent to some compute engine which resides at the sonar server. This is where the issues are created, assigned e.t.c. So, the information regarding the issue will no longer be available even in some PostJob.

1. User finder alternative: I am now using the user web service to fetch information I require as far the author of the issue is concerned.
2. IssueFilter helps me lay my hands on each issue that is reported.

My purpose here is to create a custom report immediately after the analysis where a link to each issue is shown. I don't think I'll be able to achieve this using the sonar plugin.

Comment: Why don't use notifications to send emails to users ?

Comment: Note that Decorator was replaced by MeasureComputer in 5.2 (your tag is about 5.0). MeasureComputer allows to get issues and settings.

Comment: Thnx for the response. I send all the new issues introduced to each author in a custom format. Not sure if notifications and notification channel will help me achieve this. Will they?

Comment: My present strategy however, is to accumulate all the new issues mapped to their author using an IssueFilter. And send the collective mails using a PostJob.

A challenge I might face here is, that the Issue object I receive in the issue filter reveals no information about its origin resource, which was very easily available with the Decorator.

Comment: WANRING: Do not rely on the fact that analysis results are available on server side. Starting from 5.x
 * it is an asynchronous processing on server side.

After reading this, I wonder, is it even possible to access the results on the server side?

Comment: I even explored notifications. But that is something the user himself can turn off. Also, there is no way to programmatically turn on for a user. Correct?